# Form close after button click with no this.close() call

Tags: c#, winforms, click, form-submit

This is a simple question, but i don´t know where is the problem. I have a form that have some code, when i click into "crear" button, in that button i call to the function "Comprobar" that cheks if the textboxs are empty, if "Comprobar" is false then i show a message.

The problem: After clicking the button "Crear" the form show the message (if all are empty) and then the form close.

Here is the code

```
public partial class FrmNuevaCita : MetroForm
    {
        DataTools mytool = new DataTools();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
       // string searchDate = "";
        int codigoPaciente = -1;

        FrmBuscarPaciente BuscarPaciente = new FrmBuscarPaciente();

        public FrmNuevaCita()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BuscarPaciente.SetCode += new EventHandler(YouCliked);


        }


        private void YouCliked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            codigoPaciente = BuscarPaciente.GetCodigoPaciente;
            //MessageBox.Show("Codigito es " + codigoPacienteActual.ToString());
            txtPaciente.Text = codigoPaciente.ToString();

        }

        public DateTime SetDate
        {
            set { dtpFechaCita.Value = value; }
        }
        private void mbCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void metroRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.cmbHora.Items.Clear();

            if (metroRadioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                this.cmbHora.Items.AddRange(new object[] 
                      {"8:00","8:30","9:00","9:30","10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30"});

            }

            else if (metroRadioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                this.cmbHora.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30","16:00","16:30","17:00","17:30","18:00","18:30","19:00" });

            }
        }

        private void mtBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BuscarPaciente.Show();
        }

        private void mbCrear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Comprobar()==false)
            MessageBox.Show("Por favor complete todos los campos");
        }

        private bool Comprobar()
        {
            bool result = false;


            if (txtPaciente.Text.Trim().Length != 0 && txtObservaciones.Text.Trim().Length != 0  && cmbHora.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
                result = true;

            return result;
        }






    }
```

Comment: could you please show us your design file aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that "Clear" button has `DialogResult` property set to `DialogResult.None`.
And that form's `CancelButton` property is not set to "Clear" button.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that my "Crear" button has DialogResult property set to DialogResult.OK

Answer (score 1):

have you debug it step-by-step?
Possible Problems:

1. The "CancelButton"-Option of your form is set to the "mbCrear_Click"-Button.
2. There might be some missformed linking of the events in your Form's Designerfile.
3. "mbCancelar_Click"-Event & "mbCrear_Click"-Event refers to the same button

Best thing would be, to set a breakpoint to "mbCrear_Click" and debug it step by step then you see where your form is closed. ;)

Hope i could help